Risc-V loop printing one element
print_list:
# Function to traverse the linked list and print the values
# Inputs: a1 = head of the linked list
    #.include "lab4_testbench.asm" 
    #using temp. register, loop thru list until u reach end. address pointer = NULL
    #print each value, move to next value
    
    mv t0, a1 #moving head of linked list to register t0 ADDRESS
    #could this be the reason?
loop:
    beqz t0, arnold #if next address leads to NULL, stop printing. end of list reached.
    
    
    lw a0, 0(t0) #a0 has KEY. accessed from address stored in t0
    print_int(a0) #print the element
    
    print_str(comma_space)
    
    lw t0, 4(t0) #t0 ADDRESS updating to next ADDRESS in linked list
    
    #beqz t0, loopinthesoup #if next address leads to NULL, stop printing. end of list reached.
    j loop #repeat until null is reached. 

arnold:
    print_str(endoflistmsg)
    print_str(newline)
    ret


I'm having an issue printing values from a list that feeds into a function print_list. For whatever reason, it only prints one element from a list, the greatest one, which is a separate issue in a different file.
I'm not sure if I'm pointing to incorrect addresses, or if I'm not retrieving them correctly. I have a hunch that says there's something wrong with the loop itself, but I'm not sure
It also comes back with list index out of range.

"I'm not sure if I'm pointing to incorrect addresses" — get to know your data, then you'll recognize correct vs. incorrect addresses, and you will be able to tell as you're debugging.  For example, you can use the debugger to identify the addresses of global data, labels, etc..
